# Android refresh screen aftet button clicked

Tags: android

I have an `Activity`. It's `Layout` has 2 `Buttons`. When I click the first `Button` a `Dialog` opens . `Dialog` contains a `ListView`. When I close the `Dialog` I want to do refresh on `Activity`. So the text of the first `Button` will be different.

```
sportSuvis.setText("Sports "); 
sportSuvis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override 
      public void onClick(View v) { 
        SportListViewDiaolog myDialog = new SportListViewDiaolog(v.getContext(),"",null); 
       myDialog.show(); 
       } 
});
```

after dialog dismiss I want to do refresh

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"option1", "option2", "option3"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick an option");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
  //  Update the second button text here 
 btn.settext("My Other Text");
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("your_string");
```

Comment: sportSuvis.setText("Sports ");
  sportSuvis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
         SportListViewDiaolog myDialog = new SportListViewDiaolog(v.getContext(), "",
                null);
           myDialog.show();
   


    
   }
  });  after dialog dismiss I want to do refresh

Comment: to change the text of a button you don't need to refresh the UI, because the current threat is the UI threat and if you make any change it is executed immediately.